# Multiplicacion y suma de Resultados de un Foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola compañeros de StackOverFlow, actualmente estoy intentando hacer una multiplicación de porcentajes %, pero actualmente no he podido realizar dicha operación,

Teniendo en cuenta que es un `foreach` que me carga ambos `inputs` .peso y .calificación las veces que exista un registro necesito hacer la siguiente operación:

Calificación * Peso + Calificación * Peso + calificación * peso y así sucesivamente dependiendo del numero de registros que me arroje el ciclo `foreach`.

Un ejemplo de datos serian los siguientes ya que estoy trabajando con porcentajes y decimales

Adjunto imagen para mayor comprensión
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente

```
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.listobjetivos)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Nombre_Objetivo</td>
                    <td><input class="peso" type="text" value="@item.Peso_Objetivo" />%</td>
                    <td>@item.Descripcion_Objetivo</td>
                    <td><input class="calificacion" type="text" value='@string.Format("{0:F1}", item.calificacion)' /></td>
                    <td>@item.observacion</td>
              </tr>
            }
<span class="resultado"></span>
```

Necesito multiplicar el peso que es un porcentaje % por la calificación y lo mismo para los demás registros pero necesito un resultado total de la suma de todos

Aqui les dejo una imagen en excel para que me puedan entender un poco mejor, en la imagen se ve la operacion en excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Ejemplo Calificación: 1.5 * Peso: 5%, Resultado: 0,075

Quedo atento a cualquier duda o novedad.

Comment: No tienes que borrar la pregunta, tambien puedes editarla si quieres cambiar los `tags`

Comment: de paso si puedes darle algunos valores a los inputs, todavia tienen el @... de mvc

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta :S

Comment: @ByGroxD edite mi respuesta espero te sirva de ayuda (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Respuesta edita :**

- Para esta solución utilize jQuery, ya depende de ti si lo utilizas.
- En primera creo las funciones por separado para la suma de los **pesos** y las **calificaciones** utilizando un `.each`.
- Luego en la `suma_total` capture los `return` de las funciones antes mecionadas.
- Como puedes ver creo una funcion llamada `cantidad_filas` ya que en la imagen que muestras hay 5 filas pero solo estan llenas 4, eso dependera de ti, si validas que las filas esten vacios o no.

### Espero mi respuesta te sirva de ayuda

```js
function suma_total() {
    var sum = 0; 
    var total=0;
    var calificacion = suma_calificacion();
    var peso = suma_peso();   
    var filas = cantidad_filas();   
    console.log('Suma de los pesos        : '+peso);    
    console.log('Suma de las calificacion : '+calificacion);  
    console.log('Numero de filas          : '+filas); 
    total=(calificacion*peso)/100;
    total=total/filas;
    console.log("El promedio es           : "+total);    
    $("#resultado").html(total);    
}

function suma_calificacion() {

var sum = 0;
    $('.calificacion').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    return sum;  
}

function suma_peso() {   
      
var sum = 0;
    $('.peso').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    return sum; 
}

function cantidad_filas() { 

var nFilas = $("#tabla_ventas tr").length;
      var nColumnas = $("#tabla_ventas tr:last td").length;
      var msg = "Filas: "+nFilas+" - Columnas: "+nColumnas;
      //console.log(msg);
      return nFilas; 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
suma_total();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla_ventas">
<tbody>                                       
<tr id="dato">
<td>peso <input class="peso" id="peso" value="5"/></td>
<td>calificacion <input class="calificacion" id="calificacion" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="dato">
<td>peso <input class="peso" id="peso" value="5"/></td>
<td>calificacion <input class="calificacion" id="calificacion" value="0.5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="dato">
<td>peso <input class="peso" id="peso" value="5"/></td>
<td>calificacion <input class="calificacion" id="calificacion" value="1.5"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="dato">
<td>peso <input class="peso" id="peso" value="5"/></td>
<td>calificacion <input class="calificacion" id="calificacion" value="1.5"/></td>
</tr>
 </tbody>
 </table> 
 <br>
 <div id="">Total :</div>
 <label id="resultado">Total :</label>
 <br>
```

Comment: Hola amigo muchas gracias por tu respuesta sin embargo, como podria hacer para que me siguiera sumando los input con ese id calificacion por el id peso? el foreach me crea varios input con el mismo nombre puede ser clase o id

Comment: Puedes utilizar una tabla y sumar los tr o td? explicame como esta conformada tu vista

Comment: Hola amigo aqui te subi una imagen, y si efectivamente son varios tr dependiendo de los registros que existan aqui puedes ver la imagen... recuerda que es peso * calificacion + peso * calificacion y asi sucesivamente http://image.ibb.co/bRRZXk/image.png

Comment: Te recomiendo cerrar esta pregunta, ya que seria otra respuesta, tu pregunta ponlo como sumar tr dentro de una tabla para que te lluevas opciones parte de la mia

Comment: hola amigo, no veo la necesidad puesto que expuse que es un foreach independientemente de que use una tabla, espero puedas ayudarme.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta pero aun estoy armando la segundda parte lo peudes coger para que hagas la otra pregunta

Comment: Hola compañero ivan actualmente no me funciona el codigo que pusiste hace poco

Comment: Estoy trabajanado en eso, pero tengo que trabajar por otro lado x eso modifique tu pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61262/discussion-between-bygroxd-and-ivan-more-flores).

Comment: @ByGroxD estas ahi?

Comment: La operacion al final de cuentas la realice con C#, mas sin embargo tu respuesta es correcta

Comment: ejjeje ntp en mi pais hubo 2 dias de feriado mas el fin de semana jejeje pero recuerda el meme "El futuro es hoy viejo"

Answer (score 1):

cual es el motivo por el cual deseas hacer foreach ??

```js
$("#dale").on('click', function(){
  var peso = $('#peso').val();
    var calificacion = $('#calificacion').val();
    var total = ((peso / 100) * calificacion).toFixed(3);
    document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="peso" value="" />
<input id="calificacion"  value="" />
<button id="dale">
DALE
</button>
<span id="spTotal"></span>
```

Comment: Hola, muy buena tu respuesta sin embargo te explico lo del foreach, has te cuenta que tengo 10 input con la clase peso y 10 input con la clase calificacion, entonces necesitaria hacer esto mismo, pero que vaya sumando cada resultado